# What is the meaning and origin of "Butzen"?

Tags: etymology, dialect, regional

Presently around the Swabian-Alemannic "*Fasnet*" we can often read of *"Butzenzunft"*, or *"Butzenlauf"*, or "*Butzen*", obviously referring to people in traditional costumes.

[Image showing a "*Butzen*"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHXvF.jpg)
<sup>Wikimedia</sup>

There are some other references to this word e.g. in this children's song:

> Es tanzt ein Bi-ba Butzemann
>   In unserm Haus herum, dideldum,
>   Es tanzt ein Bi-ba Butzemann
>   In unserm Haus herum.

The swabian term for an apple core ***"Apfelbutzen"*** may also be related.

I am wondering if this is an entirely regional word from alemannic dialects, or if it has a wider etymologic origin lost over time in other German regions. Is there anything known on the origin and meaning of *"Butzen"*? Did it survive in any other related German expressions?

Comment: Ich wusste gar nicht, dass ihr Schwaben was mit Fastnacht am Hut habt :D

Comment: I know that song from my childhoot, but i have never heard any of those words (nürnberg/augsburg)

Comment: @Em1 Nein, die Schwaben nicht, nur die Alemannen.

Comment: @Deve Nun, Rottweil und Bad Saulgau (die Hochburgen der Schwäbischen Fasnet) gehören nicht unbedingt zur alemannischen Sphäre.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Im [Wikipedia-Artikel zu *Butzemann*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butzemann) steht:

> Sprachlich ist der Begriff vermutlich aus dem mittelhochdeutschen Wort bôzen oder bessen „schlagen, poltern, klopfen“ abgeleitet.[1](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butzemann) Eine andere mögliche Namensherleitung ist verbutzen (verhüllen, vermummen; vom langobardischen Wort pauz). Im Sächsischen (Raum Dresden) gibt es die Bezeichnung "Mummum".

Im Buch [Deutsche Mythologie von Jacob Grimm](http://books.google.it/books?id=onxLAAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) steht auf Seite 289:

[image: bozen Butzenmann]

Das Wort *Apfelbutzen* könnte tatsächlich denselben Ursprung haben:

> In der Duden-Etymologie wird davon ausgegangen, dass "Butzen" zu dem im vor einigen hundert Jahren untergegangenen althochdeutschen Verb "boszan" (stoßen, schlagen, klopfen) gehört und "abgeschlagenes, kurzes Stück" bedeutet. So wie Küchenabfälle beschaffen sind, eine einleuchtende Erklärung.

([Quelle](http://content.stuttgarter-zeitung.de/inhalt.dialekt-was-bedeutet-bitzich.fca5444d-0069-4bdb-9a24-c828ea06c935.html))

Eine andere [Quellen](http://www.boari.de/woerterbuch/woerterbuch.htm) besagt allerdings, dass *Apfelbutzen* von

> puto (beschneiden, behauen) = das Kerngehäuse entfernen

abgeleitet wurde.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is related at all, but if it refers to a piece of clothing it might: I know *Butz* as a dialect word for trousers. It is a Ripuarian dialect, so maybe the word traveled along the Rhine.

See this link for the more explanations of the word and different variants of it:
[mitmachwoerterbuch](http://www.mitmachwoerterbuch.lvr.de/detailansicht.php?Artikel=Bux&Eintrag1=1235)